# How to query Pandas df based on row values and column header with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to query the df based on the row values and column header? Looking to pass through `Disney`, `World`, and `Value` as variables to return `55`. I tried using the `df.loc` function but received errors. The `Key1` and `Key2` headers are set as the `df.index`.

**Pandas Dataframe**

| Key1 | Key2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Disney | World | 55 |
| Disney | Land | 97 |

Comment: @Reinderien Doesn't seem to work, gives an error saying there is no `df.Key1` or `df.Key2` attribute.

Comment: @Reinderien the `headers` are the index set by `df.set_index(['Key1', 'Key2'], inplace=True)`. Is there something I am missing to get that error?

Comment: Oh, you have a multi-index with levels of Key1, Key2, and only one column called Value.

Comment: @Reinderien Yeah, could be multiple columns though beyond `Value` column with the indexes remaining static. Passing the variables in to account for the dynamic columns. But is there something I'm missing on the initial recommendation?

Comment: `df.Value['Disney', 'World']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you create a function, pass the parameters and get the value in return

```
df=df.set_index(['Key1', 'Key2'])

def findval(df, Key1, Key2):
    return df.loc[(Key1, Key2), 'Value']

findval(df, 'Disney', 'Land')
```

RESULT:

97

OR

```
def findval(df, Key1, Key2):
    return df[(df['Key1'] == Key1) & 
              (df['Key2'] == Key2)]['Value']

findval(df, 'Disney', 'Land')
```

1    97
Name: Value, dtype: int64

Comment: Don't do this. You don't need explicit key comparison predicates when they're already indices.

Comment: I mean, not really? This is such a simple operation that it doesn't deserve its own function `findval`. And you shouldn't be calling `set_index`, because OP claims to have already done that. Moreover, you're selecting an example opposite to the example value that the OP asked for, which is needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need this if key1 and key2 are in the index as a multiindex.

```
df.loc[('Disney', 'World'), 'Value']
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for a dynamically-selected column. For the OP's fixed column of `Value` the alternative that doesn't require a tuple is to select the column's series first, and then index into it with the two keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can get values of 'Value' to with this code

```
pd.read_csv(PATH)
data = data.dropna()
Value = data['Value'].values # Get values of 'Value'
# Key2 = data['Key2'].values # Get values of 'Key2'
print(Value)
```

And output will be

```
[55, 97]
```

Comment: Looking to only extract 55, based on the variables, as mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Just issue a multi-index expression on the series directly:

```
df.Value['Disney', 'World']
```